# Search strategy clarification for a systematic scoping review on existing statistical gene-based prediction methods

Tags: references, filter, database, systematic-review

In a systematic scoping review, I use the following databases: MEDLINE, Embase, Scopus and Web of Science. In MEDLINE and Embase, I use MeSH terms only to exclude animal and plant studies, but not exclude humans. For example, "(last query) not (exp Animals/ exp Plants/ not humans.sh.)" in MEDLINE. I do not use the check box to include only humans for safety. It is known that Scopus and Web of Science has no MeSH terms, neither an inbuilt human filter. In that case, is it fine, and/or correct not to filter humans in Scopus and Web of Science searches, but filter humans in MEDLINE and Embase searches? Every other search criteria remains the same.

I found the following details from a library website:

> Can't find a quality, recognised filter for your database and platform/interface?

In this case you can either:

- Not use a filter for that database and leave it to the screening (most sensitive approach)
- Create your own filter drawing on other strategies, testing and the review team's expertise

The second option is most commonly adopted when the number of records is problematic for screening given your available resources.

Note: If you edit or update a validated filter, or apply it outside its tested database or subject area, it is no longer considered validated – so you cannot guarantee the level of sensitivity and/or precision."

Source:
https://guides.library.unisa.edu.au/SystematicReviews/SearchFilters

According to this explanation, does it mean that making such adjustments across databases is acceptable?